# inequality funny question

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

I'm not sure what they want here:

solve the inequality in realtion to $x$
for various values of $a$ : $\frac{(a+2)x}{a-1}  - \frac{2}{3} < 2x-1$

Comment: consider cases when $a=-2$ or $a=1$ or $a \neq -2,1$.

Comment: Try sketching the two lines. How does the LHS change as $a$ is varied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Anurag A comments, separate it into cases (but you don't need to care about $a=-2$.):

(1) When $a\lt 1$, multiplying the both sides by $3(a-1)\lt 0$ will give you
$$3(a+2)x-2(a-1)\color{red}{\gt} 3(a-1)(2x-1)$$
$$\iff (-3a+12)x\gt -a+1\iff x\gt\frac{-a+1}{-3a+12}.$$
This is because $a\lt 1\Rightarrow -3a\gt -3\Rightarrow -3a+12\gt 9\gt 0$.

(2) When $a\gt 1$, multiplying the both sides by $3(a-1)\gt 0$ will give you 
$$3(a+2)x-2(a-1)\color{red}{\lt} 3(a-1)(2x-1)$$
$$\iff (-3a+12)x\lt -a+1.$$
Here, be careful about the sign of $-3a+12$. Also, what happens when $-3a+12=0$?

Comment: @Bak1139: Can you take from here? I hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah it was quite insightful, thank you

Comment: @Bak1139: You are welcome!